# Ag-grid selection does not reset after quick filtering

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid for the first time, so I am not sure if this is a bug or not.

I use setQuickFilter to filter rows based on some string.

```
api.setExcludeHiddenColumnsFromQuickFilter(true);
api.setQuickFilter(filterText);
```

That works fine. However, lets say that user has selected some row, then applied filtering, and now filtered rows do not contain the selected row.

I would assume that if row is not displayed after filtering, then it should not remain selected - it should automatically be removed from selected items.

Has anyone faced this issue?